# Copy list of files from s3 bucket to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a list of files that i want to copy from one s3 bucket for another. I know i can create a loop iterating over the file names and copy them using `aws s3 cp command`.
But there are hundreds of files and i don't want to make that many api calls. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than programatically looping over AWS provides a single command to allow you to synchronise files with only those that have changed being copied.

To do this use the [sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command from the CLI.

An example of this is below

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket s3://mybucket2
```

Under the hood this is managing the listing and copying in the most efficient way that is possible, and as I mentioned should only copy the files if they have changed or are new in the destination bucket.

Comment: Yes i came across that command. But the thing is it checks for the whole bucket before starting to copy data. The bucket has 50TB+ size of data and it takes more than 90mins to start the data copy. I am looking something that can help with a quick solution for copying the list of files that i have.

Comment: I see, do yo have a specific prefix for the objects that will reduce this?

Comment: Nope. Objects are from different paths. I guess will have to go with individual API calls for each object.